2FA with UserManager not validating
I'm sure I'm missing something with how this works. I generate the token, email the token, then redirect to a page where the user enters the token. I then validate but it's always false even though I did enter the correct token. What I'm not following is how does TwoFactorSignInAsync() actually validate the token to the user? I don't see this token stored anywhere for it to look up?
My assumptions would be token is generated, token is stored in memory/db along with user. When TwoFactorSignInAsync() runs it checks token/user against this stored token/user to see if it exists/is correct but I don't see how that is happening so I must be missing something.
Note that I'm trying not to use a password for this so anything related to password sign in is skipped so not sure if that's causing some things to not be in the right state here.
Generation
 // Generate 2FA token
            var token = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider);

            // Send token to user's email
            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Your 2FA Code", $"Your security code is: {token}");

            // Redirect to 2FA verification step
            return RedirectToAction("Verify2FA", new { model.Email });

Validating
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            // Verify the 2FA code
            var result = await _signInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync(TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider, model.Code, false, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // Successfully logged in
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid code.");
            return View(model);

